# Record Retention to File System

Tags: 2013, records-management, ecm, archive, retention

The goal is to archive records. But, in case these archived records need to be retrieved from tapes or backup systems, I want to have the ability to maintain at least some of the metadata by adding/renaming the filename. The file names are digits.

Assuming a SP 2013 farm environment. I have a record library that has a date column called "Set For Archiving On". Once the value in this date column plus one year is reached, I want to perform the following actions:

1. Rename the file using some of the record fields (or, create a folder structure using the record fields)
2. Send the record to a file system

Is this functionality provided out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [policy features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262490.aspx#section4) you have the ability to start a **workflow**. With a workfow you can [rename the file using the metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164026.aspx) of the document.

Moving the document to a filesystem could be done by creating a [custom workflow action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163911.aspx) and then use this action in the workflow.

The workflow can be created with SharePoint designer. The custom action will need Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

What i am thinking, in this scenario write a custom timer job which runs either daily or weekly or whatever time you select.

Check the Set for Archiving field and meet the Plus 1 year requirement...then your custome timer job change the file name and move it to file system.

OOTB as you asked, AFAIK this is not possible.

You can aslo check if SkyDrive Pro help in this.